# Laravel NotFoundHttpException on all routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

It's laravel version 5.4 and I'm using api.php routes. Following is one of my route in it:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api'], function() {
    Route::get('auth/test',function(){
        return "asd";    
    });
});
```

it's giving error on all routes even if I write route in web.php, it's not even loading home page:

```
http://localhost/bradforduniversityproject/public/
```

I have run following command too:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

nothing is working just giving NotFoundHttpException whatever i write in URL. Any help what could be the reason. thanks!

Following is my api.php file:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api'], function() {
    Route::get('auth/test2',function(){
        return "asd";    
});

Route::post('auth/test','Auth\LoginController@test');
Route::post('auth/login','Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('auth/register','Auth\LoginController@register');
Route::post('auth/forgotPassword','Auth\LoginController@forgotPassword');
});
```

Comment: `api.php` routes have `/api` prefix, so your route should be accessible like this `/api/auth/test`, `/api/abc`, `/api/bcd`

Comment: @Webinion still not working, http://www.bradforduniversityproject.com/mymup/public/api/auth/test

Comment: @UmairMalik what does `php artisan route:list` output?

Comment: now its throwing `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error, check method of your route.

Comment: @Webinion we can only write post route in api.php? php artisan route:list shows only post methods in it but it does have a get route too as shown above.

Comment: if your `route:list` have an entry for GET `/auth/test` then it should work, if not then its conflicting with some other route, please try with post method too.

Comment: @Webinion please check my post, i have added api.php code above. by changing get route to test2 it's now showing in list but still giving 404 message

Comment: You are requesting by  GET but in your route auth/test is POST

Comment: i have updated above route to auth/test2 and using that, and also why my web.php route not working, whatever i write in it isn't working.

Comment: check by remove namespace

Comment: Are your controllers really in the Api namespace? The default namespace is `App\Http\Controllers` I think. Have you moved them?

Comment: Double check your routes' methods (GET and POST). Could you share your web.php?

Comment: @doncadavona web.php file is empty, and even if i put a simple get route in it it's giving error of notfoundexception.. everything else is fine and checked it again..

Comment: Your api/ routes are working to me. All of them. Double check your methods. Maybe you're confused with GET and POST: Entering your route via a browser's URL bar will trigger a GET, in your case, most of your routes are POST except /auth/test2, so the others will definitely return 404. This works: http://www.bradforduniversityproject.com/mymup/public/api/auth/test2